# How to use selector when we swap on piano type buttons in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

i want to change image draw-able when am swap on different buttons(dragging finger on buttons).how can a use selector piano type buttons in android![enter image description here][1]

```
 public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();

            if (action != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN 
                && action != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE 
                && action != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) return false;

            Rect hitRect = new Rect();
            LinearLayout button;

            for(int i = 0; i < myButton1.size(); i++) {
                button = myButton1.get(i);
                button.getHitRect(hitRect);
                if (hitRect.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY())) {
                myButton1.get(i).setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_down));  

                    //  SoundManager.playShoot(i);
                }
            }
            return true;
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing drawable , you can create a xml file for the button and place it in the drawable folder. and you have to create two version of the button with the help of selector.and in button background you have to set that xml file from drawable.